# jquery ui datepicker dynamic multiple ranges for years

Tags: jquery, dynamic, datepicker, range

I'm working with the jQuery UI datepicker and have a table setup with each cell representing a specific year.  When the user selects two different ranges of years (say 1950-1960, and 1990-2000), I want only those selected years to appear in the datepicker's year drop-down menu.  I have the list of years in an array "dates_selected" - but I'm not sure how to restrict the years in this datepicker to the years listed.  Is there a way I can combine two sets of year ranges (yearRange: '1950:1960', '1990:2000') or something similar?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you are going to need to look at the options provided by the JQuery UI in particular the [minDate](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-minDate) and [maxDate](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-maxDate) values, if as you suggest you have already completed the collection of the years it is relatively simple to add these to your options.

hope this helps

Comment: If I add years as you suggest, (minDate: 1950, maxDate: 2000), I'll end up with the years 1961-1989 being available as well, which I do not want.
An alternative route could be doing this, and excluding particular ranges of years (such as 1961-1989), but I'll need to know how to to multiple excludes as well (if they select 3 separate ranges of years, I'll need two ranges of excludes)

Comment: sorry I misunderstood your intention I believe you had two separate date pickers but do I now get it right you just wish the selected ranges to appear in a single datepicker?